# In HTML, how can I have two hyperlinks next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have checked the similar questions and solutions here and am not getting any to work. I have this HTML content:

```html
<a class="link" href={url}>
  <span class="linkInner">View</span>
</a>
```

And here is the CSS content:

```css
.link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--t-bg);
    font-size: var(--f-u2);
    font-weight: 700;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    opacity: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: opacity 150ms linear;
  }
  .linkInner {
    padding: 0.375em 1em;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.4, 0.6, 1), border-color 1s linear;
    transform: translateY(25%);
  }
```

This works fine. A "View" link transitions into place.

However, when I try to add a second link, only the second link is displayed.

```
<a class="link" href={frontmatter.url}>
  <span class="linkInner">Go to Website</span>
</a>
```

I have tried separate divs wrapping in ul / li with style="display:inline-block;" without the CSS and am just not getting a solution.

Comment: They are both displayed .. One is just ON TOP of the other .. Since the position of  **both** elements is `absolute` , and since being set in a **class** ...  **both** elements are `absolute` --    `top:0`  -- `left:0`

Comment: The absolute position really doesn't make sense here. Just erase it and the elements will be above each other, in the natural document flow.

Comment: In my browser, both links are displayed one on top of the other when I change opacity of .link class to a value greater than zero. For instance opacity: 100%; .... Without changing the opacity, all I see is a white blank page with a link pointer when I hover over the page. You can give the links different classes like .link1 and .link2 then alter their attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address my comment earlier .. View the commented out parts of your CSS here and hit the "View Code Snippet" button  .. You were setting your elements on top of one-another.

```css
.link {
/*    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #FFF; /* Changed for viewing in snip */
    font-size: var(--f-u2);
    font-weight: 700;
/*    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    opacity: 0; */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: opacity 150ms linear;
  }
  .linkInner {
    padding: 0.375em 1em;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.4, 0.6, 1), border-color 1s linear;
    transform: translateY(25%);
  }
```

```html
<!-- added this div for view only -->
<div style="background-color:#000; width:100%; height:100%">
    <a class="link" href={url}>
       <span class="linkInner">View</span>
    </a>


    <a class="link" href={frontmatter.url}>
       <span class="linkInner">Go to Website</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wanted the link to appear over an image and clicking the View link would show more details on that image/subject, while clicking the "Go to Website" will do as it says. With those two lines commented out, the two links do appear, further down the screen but only one link appears at a time. If I hover the mouse further down the page the View appears and if I hover a little further down the "Go to Website" link appears. Ideally both would be over the image instead of now below it and both would be side by side.  Perhaps I need to use "standard" links.